# NiFi- wait till all my processors are finished without losing flowfile content

Tags: apache-nifi

Before we get into my problem, a quick (and simplified) overview of my NiFi Flow:
I get a csv file from a fileserver, convert it into json and split the array. So I now have one FlowFile for each line in my original csv file. I now transform each of the FlowFiles, depending on some conditions. Some of the FlowFiles will be routet to multiple transformations, which means, some FlowFiles will be split again (by the RouteOnAttribute processor) and become multiple FlowFiles once more. In the end, I want to merge the files back into one big file. So my flow looks something like this:

GetFile -> ConvertRecord -> SplitJson -> RouteOnAttribute to several transformations -> Funnel Everything -> MergeContent

Now, I want to make sure that every FlowFile that belongs to that first csv file ends up in the same final file. I tried using the scheduling-time in the MergeContent processor but that is way too unreliable. I looked into Notify and Wait but I simply cannot get it to work. I don't want to wait after my split and continue on success because I would lose all my transformations. Also, I cannot use the ${fragment.count} - attribute that my split processor is giving me because one of my FlowFiles might have been routet to different transformations and ended up as multiple FlowFiles.

I cannot find a way to merge every FlowFile from that original csv into a final file. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Find a way to use ${fragment.count}. If you splitted something in the middle then merge it before the final merge.

Comment: If I merge it again in the middle, I have the same problem again. Since my FlowFiles were routet to different processors, I'd have to merge my files again without knowing how many I need to merge and if I got all of them or missed some because one of my processors took longer to tranform the input.

Comment: could you please explain what's in your flow that you don't know the number of files? each split produces the number of new files...

Comment: The issue is my RouteOnAttribute processor. In that, I specify different relationships like "Attribute 1 equals something" and "Attribute 2 equals something". If both of these are true, my Flowfile is routet to both relationships, hence I get two FlowFiles originated in the same one that I need to merge once again. But I cannot tell how many will match both relationships.

Comment: so, to simplify your question - how to merge all flowfiles  originated by the same one after RouteOnAttribute  processor - is it correct?

Comment: Yes, in combination with a SplitJson processor. But I'd be happy with merging all FlowFiles that were created by my RouteAttribute processor. I can always deal with the split ones seperately.

Comment: The idea with routeonattribute - keep predictable number of files in output. Just create another  condition that will compensate conditions that not worked. For example you have conditions A, B, and C - create  `not A` `not B` `not C` - you'll have always 3 output files and quite easy to merge 3 files... Think about not to use router with multiple valid conditions.